# pkg_add can't install anything on openbsd 6.1

Tags: openbsd

When I attempt to pkg_add screen or any other pkg, I see:

```
ftp://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/4.8/packages/i386/screen-4.0.3p1.tgz: unsigned package (signify(1) doesn't see old-style signatures)
ftp://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/4.8/packages/i386/screen-4.0.3p1.tgz: unsigned package (signify(1) doesn't see old-style signatures)
ftp://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/4.8/packages/i386/screen-4.0.3p1.tgz: unsigned package (signify(1) doesn't see old-style signatures)
ftp://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/4.8/packages/i386/screen-4.0.3p1.tgz: unsigned package (signify(1) doesn't see old-style signatures)
ftp: local: -: Broken pipe
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection.
Can't locate object method "errsay" via package "OpenBSD::PackageRepository::FTP" at /usr/libdata/perl5/OpenBSD/PackageRepository.pm line 845.
```

/etc/pkg.conf contains: `installpath = http://ftp5.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/%c/packages/%a/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have defined `PKG_PATH` somewhere. Try this as root:

```
unset PKG_PATH; pkg_add screen
```

Comment: It was set in my root user's .profile. Thanks very much.